# Embedded Views in Drupal

Tags: drupal, view

I'm trying to straighten out the front page of my drupal-based website.  I want to display a static bit of content at the top (no link the way a sticky node would be) and then a list of the most recent posts underneath.

Doing a view of all content with the 'static' node stick is pretty close, although I don't want it to summarize the top node and I don't want the title linked.

Embedding a view within the home node is also very close, although it indents all the content and puts a double bottom line at the bottom (one for the bottom of the view, one for the bottom of the page) and the RSS icon shows up at the bottom of the view instead of the bottom/top of the page the way it would if it was a view page.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the view you should have the option to change the output of the field you are displaying.

As for the double bottom line and other style issues, check your css it may be inheriting something from there. If it's not then you can always style it with css as each view generates a unique id.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that there is a better way to do this with views, but the following should work...

Depending on the theme you are using you may have a region in about the right place (Or you could create one).

Then you could create a block with the static content in and set it to only display on the homepage. You could use the view of all content after this.

Answer (score 0):

Check node queue module http://drupal.org/project/nodequeue